# enumitem: renaming the list marker

Tags: enumitem

I am using `enumitem` to create a list.  My goal is to label each item as `Case: 1`, `Case: 2`, etc.

With the `enumerate` package, I was able to do

```
\begin{enumerate}[{Case} :1]
\item
something
...
\end{enumerate}
```

I tried this with `enumitem` but it didn't work.  I also tried `label = {Case} : 1` and `label = {Case :}` as optional arguments.  In the first try, the case didn't increase from 1, and the in the second, incrementation never started start.

How can I achieve this result with `enumitem`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[not sure what to put here for desired result]
\item
\item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it look better if the colon is at the end?

Comment: If you want to put exactly the same, just add the option `\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}`. Then the exact same syntax will be available (plus all the extra options from `enumitem`).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The package offers a set of starred versions of `\alph`, `\Alph`,
`\arabic`, `\roman` and `\Roman`, without argument, for the current counter in `enumerate`, so you can use `\arabic*` to get the Arabic representation. A little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}


\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label={\bfseries Case \arabic*:}]
\item First.
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

Or define a new dedicated list:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{ecases}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[ecases,1]{label={\bfseries Case \arabic*:}}


\begin{document}

\begin{ecases}
\item First.
\end{ecases}


\end{document}
```

[image]

As an additional useful feature, `enumitem` has a provision to handle user defined counters as well, using `\AddEnumerateCounter` or `\AddEnumerateCounter*` The following example illustrates a possible use of the non-starred variant (the example is a variation of one given in the package documentation):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeatletter
\def\ctext#1{\expandafter\@ctext\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\def\@ctext#1{\ifcase#1\or First\or Second\or Third\or
Fourth\or Fifth\or Sixth\fi}

\AddEnumerateCounter{\ctext}{\@ctext}{Second}
\makeatother

\newlist{steps}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[steps,1]{label={\ctext*:},align=left}

\begin{document}

\begin{steps}
\item do this.
\item do that.
\item don't do this.
\end{steps}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The colon in my example is after the counter; the change in position should be obvious.

Answer (score 7):

The label is changed by using the `label={\arabic*}` syntax, where it can be preceded by basically any text/construction. If letters should be used, then write `\alph*` or `\Alph*` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label={\bfseries Case \arabic*:}]
\item First
\item Second
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[label={\bfseries Case \Alph*:}]
\item \( E = mc^2 \)
\item \( c^2 = a^2 + b^2 \)
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Too many braces! `;-)` Actually `[label=\bfseries Case: \arabic*]` suffices.

Comment: @egreg: I know, but I am fond of braces, as long as they do no harm ;-)

Comment: The `%` at the end of `\begin{document}` does not harm as well. I like it. :-)